# CSpinButtonCtrl: How to remove Autobuddy style?

Tags: windows, mfc

I use a CSpinButtonCtrl, the AutoBuddy Style is set in the DialogResssource to TRUE. 
I must now remove/hide the CSliderButtonCtrl in KioskMode (FullScreen).

I have tried this, it is not enough, the associated CEditCtrl does not redraw, the place where the SpinCtrl was.

```
CMyFormView::OnInitialUpdate()
{
   if (g_bKiosMode)
   {
     m_ctlSpin1.ShowWindow(SW_HIDE);
     m_ctlSpin1.ShowWindow(SW_ENABLE);

     LONG style = GetWindowLong(m_ctlSpinSollwert1.GetSafeHwnd(), GWL_STYLE);
     style &= ~UDS_AUTOBUDDY;
     SetWindowLong(m_ctlSpinSollwert2.GetSafeHwnd(), GWL_STYLE, style);
  }
}

  }
```

tried too:

```
if (!g_bKioskMode)
{
  DDX_Control(pDX, IDC_SPIN1, m_ctlSpin1);
}
```

tried too: Subclass the CSpinCtrl, but the PreCreateWindow(..) is not called

```
class CMySpinButton : public CSpinButtonCtrl
{
 DECLARE_DYNAMIC(CMySpinButton)

  public:
  CMySpinButton();
  virtual ~CMySpinButton();

  protected:
  DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()
  virtual BOOL PreCreateWindow(CREATESTRUCT& cs);
};
```

further ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can detach a Up-Down control by sending it the `UDM_SETBUDDY` message with a NULL HWND and then hiding the window.

The Up-Down control will actually resize its buddy so you need to resize the edit control after you have detached.

Comment: No, that has not solved, the attached CEdit still assumme the UDS_AUTOBUDDY style is set.by the DialogRessource and does not redraw the detached buddy.

Comment: I solved this by removing the AutoBuddy Style in the Ressource. And set/remove with the m_ctlSpin1.SetBuddy(NULL) / SetBuddy(cEdit).